# Running short of RAM memory when calling a NumPy object

Tags: ram

I have a dual boot with Linux 16.04 and Windows 10 on an Inspiron 15 3000 series and it seems that I ran out of memory while calling for a NumPy object.
I tried to download [DrQA](https://github.com/facebookresearch/DrQA), a system for reading comprehension applied to open-domain question answering developed by Facebook research group. It included to call for the provided trained models and data for Wikipedia question answering.
I tried to run the `interactive.py` to try it but after asking my first question to the prompt but it's where it ran short of memory.

```
(wiki_env) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/WikiQueri/DrQA$ python3.6 scripts/pipeline/interactive.py 
07/19/2018 01:49:54 PM: [ Running on CPU only. ]
07/19/2018 01:49:54 PM: [ Initializing pipeline... ]
07/19/2018 01:49:54 PM: [ Initializing document ranker... ]
07/19/2018 01:49:54 PM: [ Loading /home/mike/Programing/WikiQueri/DrQA/data/wikipedia/docs-tfidf-ngram=2-hash=16777216-tokenizer=simple.npz ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/pipeline/interactive.py", line 69, in <module>
    reader_model=args.reader_model,
  File "/home/mike/Programing/WikiQueri/DrQA/drqa/pipeline/drqa.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.ranker = ranker_class(**ranker_opts)
  File "/home/mike/Programing/WikiQueri/DrQA/drqa/retriever/tfidf_doc_ranker.py", line 37, in __init__
    matrix, metadata = utils.load_sparse_csr(tfidf_path)
  File "/home/mike/Programing/WikiQueri/DrQA/drqa/retriever/utils.py", line 34, in load_sparse_csr
    matrix = sp.csr_matrix((loader['data'], loader['indices'],
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 235, in __getitem__
    pickle_kwargs=self.pickle_kwargs)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 674, in read_array
    array = numpy.ndarray(count, dtype=dtype)
MemoryError
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/pipeline/interactive.py", line 69, in <module>
    reader_model=args.reader_model,
  File "/home/mike/Programing/WikiQueri/DrQA/drqa/pipeline/drqa.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.ranker = ranker_class(**ranker_opts)
  File "/home/mike/Programing/WikiQueri/DrQA/drqa/retriever/tfidf_doc_ranker.py", line 37, in __init__
    matrix, metadata = utils.load_sparse_csr(tfidf_path)
  File "/home/mike/Programing/WikiQueri/DrQA/drqa/retriever/utils.py", line 34, in load_sparse_csr
    matrix = sp.csr_matrix((loader['data'], loader['indices'],
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 235, in __getitem__
    pickle_kwargs=self.pickle_kwargs)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 674, in read_array
    array = numpy.ndarray(count, dtype=dtype)
MemoryError
```

So I learnt that mean I run out of RAM, what could I do to cope with this error ? Is it because of the model being too big ?

Here is my memory usage from the output of `free -m`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7888        5515        1013         320        1359        1718
Swap:             0           0           0
```

and

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programming/WikiQueri/DrQA$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        8078272 kB
MemFree:          291604 kB
MemAvailable:    2326220 kB
Buffers:          262392 kB
Cached:          2212332 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          3691168 kB
Inactive:        1485432 kB
Active(anon):    2727772 kB
Inactive(anon):   274408 kB
Active(file):     963396 kB
Inactive(file):  1211024 kB
Unevictable:     2238236 kB
Mlocked:         2238252 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:               104 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       4940072 kB
Mapped:           508460 kB
Shmem:            275728 kB
Slab:             243928 kB
SReclaimable:     158948 kB
SUnreclaim:        84980 kB
KernelStack:       13024 kB
PageTables:        49456 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     4039136 kB
Committed_AS:   11909484 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:      2048 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      161648 kB
DirectMap2M:     7088128 kB
DirectMap1G:     2097152 kB
```

I need about 16 GB of RAM required I don't know how to read these table. Do you know if I can make it ?

Comment: You say you need to have 16GB of RAM, where do you get this value from?  Is this stated somewhere in relation to the object that you will need some specific RAM size to properly load this?  (You only have ~8GB of RAM)

Comment: @ThomasWard I'm trying to run [this facebook research project](https://github.com/facebookresearch/DrQA). They don't specify it but from the error I concluded from [the documentation of a Russian lab version](https://deeppavlov.ai/deeppavlov/skills/odqa/) that I needed 16GB of RAM